# parsing of an xml which having inner tags changing dynamically

Tags: java, xml-parsing, xstream

I need help in parsing one xml. Though I know xml parsing very well. but I am stuck with parsing of one particular xml which having it's inner tags changing dynamically. That xml I am getting in respoonse of some API. Sample xml is as follows:

```
   <addon_brunch_data is_array="true">
   <item>
    <Monsoon_Magic_Lunch_Buffet__Adult_>
     <currency_code>INR</currency_code>
     <pid>575</pid>
    </Monsoon_Magic_Lunch_Buffet__Adult_>
   </item>
   <item>
    <Theme_Park_Lunch>
     <currency_code>INR</currency_code>
     <pid>583</pid>
    </Theme_Park_Lunch>
   </item>
   <item>
    <All_Restaurants_except_Imagica_capital>
     <currency_code>INR</currency_code>
     <pid>553</pid>
    </All_Restaurants_except_Imagica_capital>
   </item>
</addon_brunch_data>
```

In this example, I am receiving the fixed tag `<addon_brunch_data is_array="true">` which is having an arraylist of `<item>`.

But the problem I am facing is,these inner tags of  are not fixed :

```
<Monsoon_Magic_Lunch_Buffet__Adult_>
<Theme_Park_Lunch>
<All_Restaurants_except_Imagica_capital>
```

Sometimes I am getting the inner tags of  as listed above, but sometimes the response changes as :

```
<addon_brunch_data is_array="true">
   <item>
    <Great_Indian_Food_Festival___Adult>
     <currency_code>INR</currency_code>
     <pid>575</pid>
    </Great_Indian_Food_Festival___Adult>
   </item>
   <item>
    <Great_Indian_Food_Festival___Child>
     <currency_code>INR</currency_code>
     <pid>583</pid>
    </Great_Indian_Food_Festival___Child>
   </item>
   <item>
    <Healthy_Meal_Pack>
     <currency_code>INR</currency_code>
     <pid>553</pid>
    </Healthy_Meal_Pack>
   </item>
</addon_brunch_data>
```

I need to write pojos for this, but I have not come earlier to parse such xml which is having inner tags changing dynamically like in above example I tried to give.
Guys Please help on this.

Comment: That is very poor XML design! Those custom tags should probably have been attribute values instead. Anyway, that makes it tricky but not impossible. But you haven't mentioned what you want to extract.

Comment: I am parsing xml using XStream. XStreamAlias Annotation works if tags name are known. How to use annotations if tag name is not known?

Comment: I'd say you cannot use XStream or any object deserialization technique. You may want to use an XPath-based parser instead.